# A question about boundaries of three sets with $C^1$ boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A,B,C$ are disjoint, connected open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and that each of them has a $C^1$ boundary. Suppose further $x$ is a point in the intersection of $\partial A$ and $\partial B$, and that there is a small open disc, $D$, centered at $x$, such that $\partial A \cap D = \partial B \cap D$. Is is possible that also $x \in \partial C$?

If we drop the requirement of $C^1$ boundaries it could happen that $x\in \partial C$, as the lakes of Wada show. There should be some smoothness requirement on the boundary that makes the conclusion true, but I am not sure if $C^1$-smoothness is the right one.

Comment: Wait, if you drop the requirement of $C^1$ it is true, it is possible that $x\in \partial C$.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you, I will correct it.